# MySQL only inserting first row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert a ton of rows into my MySQL database. I have a query like this, but with about 700 more repetitive entries in it but for some reason the query is only inserting the first row to the database. In this case it would be '374','4957','0'.

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('374','4957','0'),('374','3834','0'),('374','4958','0'),('374','5076','0'),('374','4921','0'),('374','3835','0'),('374','4922','0'),('374','3836','0'),('374','3837','0'),('374','4879','0'),('374','3838','0')
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What tool are you using for that query? Mysql command line? PHP?

Comment: @Kamil It was PHP but the primary key field was the issue.

Comment: Check answer I added below. That may help you in debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mean to state the obvious, but if the first field '374' is your primary key field, than this is the issue.

Otherwise, are there any error messages received from the database? That is always a good place to look for bugs.

Comment: Haha I wish that was obvious to me. But yeah that is definitely the problem. Ill accept your answer when it lets me in about 7 minutes. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For better understanding why something is not working next time use code like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('374','4957','0'),('374','3834','0')";
if (!mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
}
```

That should display error message returned from MySQL.

More information: [PHP manual - mysqli_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the column names before values.
For example:
INSERT INTO table (column1,column2,column3) VALUES ...